# What is the most secure NFC Encryption system?

Tags: encryption, authentication, mobile, nfc

What are the best ways for NFC (Near-field communication) encryption with high level of security?

Basically, I am interested in having an NFC which can only be read/authenticated with a mobile app/reader. In other words, the NFC must be encrypted in a way that no reader can copy the data and replicate the NFC.

Feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Mifare Desfire 4k

Comment: Are you looking for an existing product? I believe you can transmit/receive any data type you'd like if you implement custom software on both ends.

Comment: The 'encryption' used in NFC Credit Card transactions describes the transport encryption the mobile app and card processor server setup to secure the connection.  It's similar to how when you visit a HTTPS site TLS is encrypting your traffic.  It isn't preventing a static tag from being read or written to, but rather encrypting back and forth traffic between two NFC enabled **devices**.  You can't prevent a static tag from being cloned, it can always be read and a new tag can be written with it's contents.